# Is it possible to partially predict the addresses that will be generated?

Tags: addresses

This is the EOA wallet that generates the AA (EIP4337) created by the Versa platform.

> https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x433701c458d6d9a0b8f4bae1ccf687f20f4821ea

And this is the address of the wallet that participated in the bundler.

> https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xaa1237f4ecf226528219f87d3b0e3fca445abdf5

You can see that the wallet address is prefixed with 4337 and AA. Surprising, isn't it? My understanding is that wallet addresses are randomized.

Is it possible to partially predict the addresses that will be generated? Or was it just a coincidence?

Comment: Not predication, most likely just collision, keep generating addresses till they find one that works for vanity. Lots of examples like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite intriguing to notice that the wallet address generated for the AA (EIP4337) on the Versa platform, as well as the address of the wallet that participated in the bundler, both share the distinctive prefix of "4337" and "AA." At first glance, it might seem like there's a pattern or predictability to Ethereum addresses, but it's important to clarify a few key points.

1. **Randomness of Ethereum Addresses**: Ethereum addresses are typically generated using cryptographic processes that involve randomness. These addresses are essentially the result of applying cryptographic algorithms to private keys. As such, they are designed to be pseudorandom and virtually impossible to predict or generate intentionally.
2. **Vanity Addresses**: What you've observed here is not a coincidence but rather an example of what are commonly referred to as "vanity addresses." Vanity addresses are Ethereum addresses that have specific, user-defined prefixes or patterns. While the core of the address remains random and secure, users can choose to generate addresses with certain desired characteristics at the beginning or end. However, creating vanity addresses involves a considerable amount of computational effort and can be time-consuming.
   For example, you can use websites like [vanity-eth.tk](https://vanity-eth.tk) to generate vanity addresses. The more specific your vanity requirements (such as having "AA" or "4337" at the start), the more computational power and time it will take to find a matching address. Users can choose to include specific characters at the beginning or end of their addresses, but this is not a guaranteed process and may require significant resources.
3. **Resource-Intensive Process**: Generating vanity addresses, especially with longer or more unique prefixes, can be resource-intensive and time-consuming. It involves trial and error, with computational algorithms working through numerous possibilities until a matching address is found. The longer the desired prefix, the more computational power and time will be required.

In conclusion, while it may appear that certain Ethereum addresses follow patterns, it's important to remember that these patterns are the result of users deliberately creating vanity addresses. The core Ethereum address generation process remains highly random and secure, and predicting regular addresses is practically impossible due to the cryptographic methods involved. Vanity addresses are a unique exception and are specifically crafted for aesthetic or branding purposes, often at a considerable computational cost.

Comment: It's a randomly generated wallet.
That was a perfect comment, thank you.